# existence of a vector not contained in any proper $T$ invariant subspace implies minimal poly of $T$ has degree $dim V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n-$dimensional vector space over the field $K$ and let $T: V → V$ be a linear operator. Assume that there exists a vector $v_0 \in V$ that is contained in no proper $T-$invariant subspace of $V$. Then can we say that the minimal polynomial of $T$ over $K$ has degree equal to $n$ ?

Comment: Hint: The space spanned by $v_0$, $T\left(v_0\right)$, $T^2\left(v_0\right)$, ... is $T$-invariant.

Answer (score 1):

If $p(T) = 0$ with $\deg p = k$ and $v_0 \neq 0$ then the subspace $W = \operatorname{span} \{ v_0, Tv_0, \dots, T^{k}v_0 \}$ will be a $T$-invariant subspace with $1 \leq \dim W \leq k$. By your assumption, $V = W$ and so $k \geq \dim V = n$ and so the minimal polynomial of $T$ must have degree $n$.